# Adding cookies to Custom Tabs in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, chrome-custom-tabs, android-customtabs

I'm trying to pass a cookie to custom tabs like in webview so that the user doesn't have to login, I've seen other questions but all of them were 6+ years old so I'm wondering if it's possible to do that now. Did they implement a direct way to pass cookies or is it gonna be a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Existing answers are up to date. It's not possible to set cookie directly in a Custom Tab.